# ASP.NET Web API Help Generation Stopped - How to restart Auto Generation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

I have added ASP.NET WEB API Help Documentation to an existing Project.
Its working to an extent, as I can browse to localhost/help and I can see the Account Controller API that comes with ASP.NET MVC.
I can also see one other API controller that I have built, and its Methods.
However I have since added another 5 API controllers, and WEB API Help is failing to generate the documentation for these.

I have enabled these settings in APP_Start/HelpPageConfig of API help:

```
    config.SetDocumentationProvider(new XmlDocumentationProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/XmlDocument.xml")));
    config.SetActualRequestType(typeof(string), "Values", "Get");
    config.SetActualResponseType(typeof(string), "Values", "Post");
```

And I also have enabled XML Documentation Output in the Project Properties/Build Section as mentioned in this post:
[Creating Web API Help Pages](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-api-help-pages)

So how can I get the documentation to Automatically generate for the other 5 controllers?

Any ideas are vary welcome, and thank you in advance.

Comment: As an update, I forgot to mention that the generated XML documentation in App_Data/XMLDocument.xls (I must rename that!) actually contains all the correct documentation for ALL controllers. So it seems that the API Help is just not reading this file, or its not reading it correctly...

Comment: For further info, im using Web API 2 Help Page v5.0.0 with an ASP.NET MVC c# v5.0.0 Project

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out, so ill post an answer - hopefully it helps someone else.
I simply needed to register the Controller routes specifically in the App_Start\WebAPIConfig.cs file, and the Help Generation has resumed generating.